# Contentful to struct in swift

Tags: swift, contentful

Can anyone help with this most basic of swift Contentful examples? Just trying to get response from Contentful (working) and then map the resulting entities to my custom struct.

The Contentful swift documentation is very lacking forcing you to jump between Git repose and convoluted examples and the code snippets only refer to printing the result.

```
// Create structs that can be decoded from json
import Foundation
import Decodable

struct MyEntity {
    let name: String
}


extension MyEntity {
    static func decode(j: AnyObject) throws -> MyEntity {
        return try Entity(
            name: j => "nested" => "name"
        )
    }
}


// From other class, get the data (working) and then map it to struct objects
let client = Client(spaceIdentifier: "my_identifier", accessToken: "my_access_token")

client.fetchEntries(["content_type": "my_entity"]).1.next { result in
    for item in result.items{

        // Now what? item is not json so
        // how to i convert it to an instance of MyEntity

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
client.fetchEntries(["content_type": "my_entity"]).1.next { result in
    result.items.map ({ (item) in
        let hello = item.field["hello"] as? String
        let world = item.field["world"] as? String
    })
}
```

Be sure that all code touching UI in the success completion block is executed on main thread.